# Need to handle large database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having table with 9 columns and 400000 Records. I am using php and mysql for database. The problem I am facing is it takes quite a long time to fetch the particular data or search the records. So can anyone please suggest me should I use other database or some twicks to do in database and also sugegst me the best hosting to handle this large records in my site.

Comment: thats not very large - but we need to see your code and db schema to have any hope of helping you

Comment: 400,000 rows is not remotely large. The fact that you are experiencing slowness suggests poor use of indexes, but of course we can't know that because there is _absolutely no useful information_ in your question. At a minimum you need to provide table schema (including indexes), the queries you are running, AND the output of `explain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this much record is not considered as a large data. What you need to do is make sure you have proper [indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) in your table columns and most important to load only those data which are required. i.e. Implement paging.